# I want to redirect my page without changing my url

Tags: .htaccess

I am create a website and i have some problem in ht-access. I want to redirect my page but URL doesn't changed. Below are the code of htaccess for redirect
Note: i am working on local host Xampp server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /online-web/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^home.php$ index.php$1 [r=301,nc]
 RewriteRule ^about_us.php$ default.php$1 [r=301,nc]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `I want to redirect my page but URL doesn't changed` can you provide an example of what you mean? How does the URL look and where should it end up?

Comment: RewriteRule ^about_us.php$ default.php$1 [r=301,nc]

this will redirect successfully but it will also change url. I want url remain same about_us.php

Comment: i want that if someone enter url about_us.php then it will sucessfully redirect to default.php but in browse url will remain same about_us.php

Answer (score 0):

> ... this will redirect successfully but it will also change url. I want url remain same about_us.php

You just need to remove the `r=301` (redirect) flag from the `RewriteRule`. This will then change it to an *internal rewrite* (as opposed to an *external redirect*) and the URL in the address bar will not change. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^about_us\.php$ default.php [NC,L]
```

However, you must make sure you clear your browser cache first. The `301` (permanent) redirect will have been cached by your browser.

You should also escape the dot in the `RewriteRule` pattern in order to match a literal dot and not *any* character. eg. `^about_us\.php$`

I've also added the `L` (LAST) flag to the rule since you probably don't want any additional processing.

And I've removed the `$1` backreference, since this is not being used.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an example and more explanation.

Comment: If this answered your question then you can mark it as "accepted" (check mark on left hand side) to take it out of the unanswered question queue. (Once you have 15 reputation points then you can also upvote answers that you find useful.) Thanks.